# Logging in multithreading environment and testing

Tags: c#, c++, testing, logging

Please let me know your suggestions about how to design logging and how to test it, in the following scenario.

I've an API which can be called by multiple threads. One call of this API by a single thread generates a log of 50 KB.

Does any design pattern exist for logging in multi-threaded environment. i.e *one log file for all threads vs one dedicated log file for each thread*?

And, How to do testing for this feature. *(should it be tested?)*

Thanks.

Comment: re: "should it be tested"  haha, that's funny.

Comment: What would the performance characteristics of your scenario be? A single shared logger could be a bottleneck for CPU intensive applications, whereas in other scenarios that may not be a problem.

Comment: @John: :) i asked that as i don't know how do that? what criteria should be set. input parameters? expected output?

Comment: @Chris: performance is very much critical. but now the worry is only about accuracy and ordering of logs.

Comment: If performance really is critical, don't use a singleton.  For that matter, if good design is important, don't use a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your logging instance in a thread-safe singleton. [Don't use double check locking](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)! Also, it probably makes sense to use a logging library like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [Enterprise Library 5](http://entlib.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about logging of transactional activity, where all of the data in the 50 KB log is related to a particular transaction performed by the thread, there may be a case for a log per thread, as otherwise disentangling the output can become a significant problem.  Another solution for this particular case may actually be a single log file per transaction with a 'global' log that merely mentions on a single line that a transaction was initiated and perhaps another entry for the final result, if applicable.  A third solution is to make sure the log entries are tagged in such a way that you can determine the transaction with which each line is associated and then have post-processing tools that can filter the log to view particular transactions.

The second solution (a file per transaction) can become a problem if you have very frequent transactions, as some file system operations (notably, inspecting a folder over the network) become slow as the number of files in a directory increases.  The third solution can work well (as you can add additional features to the filtering/viewing tool), but it does mean developing and maintaining another tool.

Comment: Disentangling the output can be achieved by adding a thread-specific token to each log line. 

OP should consider that having logs spread out to separate files will make it practically impossible to figure out the relative order of events in different threads. For instance, in the domain of protocol programming it is absolutely necessary that one can reliably dig out the control flow between components in different threads at any point from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should wrap your logger instance into Singleton using double locking on creation of the instance of your logger object to protected it against the racing condition on initialization.

Comment: do you mean double check locking?

Comment: Be very careful when attempting double-check locking. Naive implementations can not work correctly based on language implementation details.  [Explanation of why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the needs of your application. If you want to be able to easily see the order in which things happened across all threads, then you would want to use a single log file and synchronize access to it between threads. If each thread more or less operates independently, and you only care about what happens in a single thread at a time, then use a separate log file per thread.

Comment: as per requirement, it is up to developers to use single file or more. Which should be better? as i don't find much difference between the two if i add the timestamps with each log.

Comment: Yes, you can cross-reference timestamps between separate log files, but assuming your log entries are in chronological order inside your log file, it's much easier to see the order in which things happened.

Answer (score 0):

I have in the past created Loggers that we're thread-local. There was the configurable number of LogSinks, only if the same FileSink was written to from several threads would locking come into view.

By creating the Loggers thread-local it was fairly easy to implement stack tracing (in a C/C++ code base).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best method, I use something like this in my code

```
void Log( const char* msg ) {
#ifdef ENABLE_LOGGING
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_mutex); 

    // do a fprintf or what you want
#endif
}
```

The mutex ensures this function executes only one at a time when you call from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

For high performance logging take a look into the [Microsoft Message Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811056.aspx) (MSMQ).

Each thread can write to the same message queue, while a separate service/process can read from the queue and store the data in your log storage format.  This avoids any contention between the threads and maximizes performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an in memory queue (they new ones in .NET 4 System.Collections.Concurrent is thread safe.
Then let one worker thread read the queue and log to file/db.